# how to pre populate fields based on search results of data base

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to stack overflow and really appreciate all the help. I currently have a database with basic columns, name id company etc. I created a search query that shifts through this list based on firstname, lastname, or timestamp date. I was able to print the results on the query page  of the search but want this to pre populate on the same form page as a new entry. i was able to link from the query page to the form page but am not sure how to populate these results on the form page.

my current query page prints as the following :

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head> 
     <title> 

      </title>
       </head>
    <body>

      <div id="container" style="width:750px;background-color:#FFFE8D;margin-left: 250px">

    <div id="Back" style="float:left; background-color:#FFFE8D;">
    <form action="http://localhost/contractor/existingcontractorpage3.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="Is this the Contractor?" style="float:right; background-color:#FFFE8D;">
    <form action="http://localhost/contractor/redirectcontractorpage.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
    </div>

<div id="info" style="width:750px;height:95px; text-align: center">

<h3> If this is the contractor, please move on to the next page using the corresponding button above. </h3>
<h3> Please enter the exact information on the next page. </h3> 
</div>

<div id="results" style="width:750px;height:225px; text-align: center">

 <?php

  $host = "localhost"; //server
 $db = ""; //database name
 $user = ""; //databases user name
 $pwd = ""; //password
 mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error()); 

$searchTerm = trim($_GET['searchname']);

  // Check if $searchTerm is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
    {
        echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
        exit();
         } 
       else 
         { 
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM contractor WHERE CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME,' ', ARRIVAL) like                                                             '%$searchTerm%'";  
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
                    $count=mysql_num_rows($query);

        if(($count)>=1)
    {
    $output = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $output .= "First Name: " . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "Last Name: " . $row['LASTNAME'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "Arrival: " . $row['ARRIVAL'] . "<br />";
     }
        echo $output;
      }
        else
       echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
}
  ?>

</div>
<br> </br>
<br> </br>  
      </body>
     </html>
```

Now ideally i would want the results to pop up here, and if possibly have a radio button to the right of each result( if there is ever more than one) to select and continue to the form page to pre populate each field. the form page is simply like this:

```
          <form action="insert_submit.php" method="post">

      First Name: <input type = "text" name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME" />

 <br>
 </br>

 Last Name: <input type = "text" name="LASTNAME" id="LASTNAME"/>

 <br>
 </br>

 Purpose: <input type = "text" name="PURPOSE" id="PURPOSE"/>

<br>
</br>
Company: <input type = "text" name="COMPANY" id="COMPANY" />

<br>
</br>

Who here to see: <input type = "text" name="WHOHERETOSEE" id="WHOHERETOSEE"/>

<br>
</br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<br>
</br>

</form>
```

thanks so much! hope to hear back soon as this is my last straw on my project.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to pull the data from the database like you're doing, except where you want to add the form into the page. Then in your loop print out form fields:

You need to give each radio a unique name. You could use an incrementing id, or you could give it the same as the row name.

Method 1:

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $output .= "<label>First Name: " . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "</label><input type=\"radio\" name = \"radio[]\" value=\"".$row['FIRSTNAME']." ".$row['LASTNAME']."\"/>";
    ..
    ..
 }
```

You will then be able to get the values from the radio buttons by using GET or POST when the from is submitted.

Setting name = "radio[]" puts all the values in an array which you can get on the next page once the form is submitted.

On the next page after form submission, $_POST['radio'] or $_GET['radio'] will return an array of all the values which you specify. Notice how the value attribute has been filled in above. Do this for each of the rows.

Also be careful about using my_sql connections. It's depreciated as of PHP 5.5.0. Use mysqli or PDO instead, it's more secure. https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect

Check it this link. it compares and provides examples on both

Comment: the radio button pops up next to each result properly. but when i click the next button, the info is lost and does not pre populate the fields.

Comment: Edited the post, look above

Comment: im not sure what is happening with this code. it is just print the firstname and isnt printing more than one case.

Comment: I've demonstrated how to do it just using the firstname. Add in any other cases/table rows in the same way

Comment: i added more cases and each case is being displayed with its own radio button. how would i make one radio button for a first name and last name pair. also i want to have them pop up on the next page pre populated which im getting errors for. this code is starting to look all junky now :(

Comment: look at the edit above. If it's not what you're trying to do, I really don't understand your problem, maybe you could break it down a little.

Comment: alright so I understand the code above and how the array will hold the info chosen and will move it to the next page after submission. My question is, how would i properly code on the next page to fill the form with the selected data. for instance, my code currently for the form is :

Comment: <form action="insert_submit.php" method="post" style="margin-left:35px;">

 First Name: <input type = "text" name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME" />

 

 Last Name: <input type = "text" name="LASTNAME" id="LASTNAME"/>


 Purpose: <input type = "text" name="PURPOSE" id="PURPOSE"/>
 
 
 <br>
 </br>
 Company: <input type = "text" name="COMPANY" id="COMPANY" />

 



 DL #: <input type = "text" name="DRIVERL" id="DRIVERL" />

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

 <br>
 </br>

 </form> 
  
</div>

Comment: what would i do to the basic form code above to get[radio] information and post it in the forms accordingly? sorry for the constant need of help. I am kinda stuck

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're connecting the query search and form page, but you could create the link back containing the data in GET params in the url, since I don't see password or private material in these fields. Then use php to populate the forms.

```
$url = "your_form_page?";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $url .= "fname=" . $row['FIRSTNAME'];
    $url .= "&lname=" . $row['LASTNAME'];
    $url .= "&arrival=" . $row['ARRIVAL'];
 }

// $url = your_form_page?fname=bob&lname=jones&arrival=blah
```

Then to populate the form..

```
<form action="insert_submit.php" method="post">

  First Name: <input type = "text" name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME" value="<?php echo $_GET['fname']; ?>" />
```

Hopefully this helps or at least gets you thinking in the right direction.

Comment: i am trying to understand the process you outlined. the error im getting has to do with the while statement and the new content in the loop. I also have not made the connection between the form and query page yet. it has just been a hyperlink to go to the form page and was a  manual entry. also  what if there are two individuals with the same last name ?